# My android virtual device is not showing contents

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have installed the SDK manager and eclipse, on starting the AVD it starts and displays as "android". Tell me what should I do run android virtual device.

Comment: Whether your emulator opened completely? Can you see Menu Icons?, If emulator is showing "android" then wait until it completely opens or create a new emulator with different configuration(API version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing everything correctly. It's just that the emulator can be super slow to boot up initially.

The simplest solution is to use a real device to test your application on.

Another solution is to create an avd with a lower api level and to set a minsdk to that lower api level to make sure your application can run on that new avd you created. Personally, I like to run an emulator with api level 10 and so a minsdk of 10 (assuming my application doesn't need any of the newer functionality).

And another solution still is to learn how to run you application on an Intel x86-based emulator (the solution referenced by Varun Das). Since your development machine is x86-based, that option runs super quickly as well.

Whatever solution you decide on, don't turn off your emulator image/reboot your phone between launches of your application, the second time you launch your app will be much quicker once the emulator/phone is already on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is the slow startup of the emulator and displays only the 'Android' logo for a long time.
From my experience I suggest you to create your AVD using an 'x86' image of the android OS.
By default the AVD gets created using the 'ARM System Image'. The emulator startups very slowly using this image in most of the users. So I recommend using the 'x86' with HAXM to speed up the emulator.
You should also refer this link:[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

virtual device take time to startup

If this is what you see from your virtual device, that means it still loading

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use genymotion check this [link](http://www.genymotion.com/). It is more useful and faster than android virtual devices on AVD.